# Accidentally "repaired GRUB" with boot-repair, how to undo the repair/reinstall backup?

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I accidentally clicked "repair GRUB", now my keyboard doesn't work until after the boot sequence.

I'm fairly certain there was a backup made (didn't change any of the settings, and new files were created), but I can't find the right instructions for what I need to do.

How do I restore the backup made by boot-repair?

Comment: It's not a direct solution to your problem, but if your computer has still USB 2.0 ports, attach your keyboard to a USB 2.0 port, instead to a USB >= 3.0 port. This should enable your keyboard again. If that also doesn't work, your BIOS has probably disabled `legacy USB support`, try to enable it.

Comment: I do not believe there is a backup. It just updates. What updates did it do? Default is often just a `sudo update-grub` which just updates grub menu. It may offer to do a full grub reinstall & update to the newest kernel which may update other software.  Keyboard issues often are in UEFI/BIOS settings. Grub does not have keyboard driver and uses the UEFI/BIOS. If Boot-Repair's updates also triggered a UEFI firmware update, UEFI then resets to defaults. Recheck UEFI settings & make sure USB keyboard & mouse are enabled or full USB support is on.

Comment: @oldfred Something likely updated itself, I was able to use the keyboard this morning strangely enough. Thanks for the knowledge nonetheless!

Cheers.

Comment: @paladin Oh, yes! I have both versions on this case. Thankfully it seemed to fix it self somehow, anyway. Thanks for sharing that trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the knowledge everyone. It just fixed itself overnight, or on the fifth/sixth reboot.

I didn't do anything except give up, and go to sleep. I suppose this a good answer to some problems!

Cheers.